# Может ли быть множественный псевдоним (AS) в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно, чтобы выполнился такой запрос:

```
SELECT
  name_EN AS AL,
  name_RU AS AL,
  name_TR AS AL
FROM
  tbl
WHERE
  name_EN LIKE '%param%' OR
  name_TR LIKE '%param%' OR
  name_RU LIKE '%param%';
```

Прошу обратить внимание на псевдоним: **AS AL** для каждого поля в SELECT.

Comment: И к какому столбцу вы надеетесь после этого обратиться по имени `AL` ?

Comment: Тогда прошу помощи, как избежать этого. Т.е. нужно выполнять поиск LIKE по полям - но вернуть название одного поля (одинаковое название).

Comment: в вопросе приведи пример таблицы и что должен вернуть запрос.

Comment: Таблица из ID, и только тех полей, которые в запросе.

Comment: Читайте на тему UNION:

     SELECT name_EN AS AL From Table Where name_EN LIKE '%param%'
     UNION SELECT name_TR AS AL From Table Where name_TR LIKE '%param%'
     UNION SELECT name_RU AS AL From Table Where name_RU LIKE '%param%'

Comment: Таблица из ID, и только тех полей, которые в запросе. А результат какой должен быть? Вам что лень написать пару строк?
Я вижу 2 варианта:
 - если Like совпадает со всеми 3-мя полями -то вывести только одно поле (к примеру name_EN;
- если Like совпадает со всеми 3-мя полями -то вывести все поля.- то пример alexlz подпилить и все ок)

Тут еще куче можно напридумывать) тут телепатов нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете назначить при помощи конструкции `AS` один и тот же псевдоним сразу нескольким столбцам в результирующей таблице. Однако, вы можете сформировать один столбец, который будет принимать найденное значение.

При формировании запроса следует помнить, что конструкция `LIKE` не обязательно применяется только в WHERE-условии, вы можете задействовать ее после оператора `SELECT`. Применив множественный выбор `CASE` вы можете выбрать именно тот столбец, который был обнаружен и уже ему назначить псевдоним при помощи конструкции `AS`.

Таким образом, ваш запрос можно переписать так

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN name_EN LIKE '%param%' THEN name_EN
    WHEN name_RU LIKE '%param%' THEN name_RU
    WHEN name_TR LIKE '%param%' THEN name_TR
  END AS AL
FROM
  tbl 
WHERE
  name_EN LIKE '%param%' OR
  name_TR LIKE '%param%' OR
  name_RU LIKE '%param%'
```